# Get unique outputs from combining more than one Django filters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

So, I am trying to create a search engine on my website where the user enters a query and I display those results where the query exists inside the product `name` or `description`. My product model is as follows:-

```py
'''Product model to store the details of all the products'''
class Product(models.Model):

    # Define the fields of the product model
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/images/products')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)    # Foriegn key with Category Model
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
```

Now, I have created a search filter where I filter by name and then by description and then combine the results to return a queryset. The issue is that sometimes the query can be found in names and in descriptions so I get repeated entries like this

[image]

My filtering code inside the ProductView is mentioned below:-

```py
class ProductView(generics.ListAPIView):
    ''' Product View to return the details of all the products and filter by ID or string '''

    # Define class variables 
    queryset = []

    # Manage a get request
    def get(self, request):
        
        ''' Display all the products in our database if no id is passed 
            and if a store ID and search is passed then use those parameters'''
        
        # Get all the parameters sent in the data 
        store_id = request.GET.get('store_id')
        search_query = request.GET.get('search')
        category = request.GET.get('category')

        print(store_id, search_query, category)
        queryset = Product.get_all_products()
        
        # Apply filters to the data
        if store_id:
            queryset = queryset.filter(store=store_id)
        
        if category:
            queryset = queryset.filter(category=category)
        
        if search_query: 
            

            # THIS IS WHERE THE SEARCH FILTERING SHOULD HAPPEN

            names = queryset.filter(name__icontains=search_query)
            descriptions = queryset.filter(description__icontains=search_query)

            queryset = list(chain(names, descriptions))
        
        return Response(ProductSerializer(queryset, many = True).data)
```

I want to be able to only get one result since it's the same product. Is there a way I can only save the distinct results in query set. I made a loop which checks the results in `descriptions` whether the item already exists in the name or not but it didn't work out very well. How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using class based views or function based?

Comment: Class based views

Comment: Ok, check the below given answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, you should never evaluate and merge two querysets results like that.

If you want to select all entities that has a name or description `icontaining` your `search_query`, use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object.

For selecting only unique objects in queryset, use [`distinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct).

So you can change the final few lines to something like this.

```
        if search_query:
            queryset = queryset.filter(
                Q(name__icontains=search_query) | Q(description__icontains=search_query)
            )
        
        queryset = queryset.distinct()  # probably won't be needed anymore
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. Thanks. It's neater and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I added a forloop to make this work but if someone has a better solution, do leave it in the comments. This is the final view I wrote.

```py
class ProductView(generics.ListAPIView):
    ''' Product View to return the details of all the products and filter by ID or string '''

    # Define class variables 
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    queryset = Product.objects.all()

    search_fields = ['name','description']
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter,)
    queryset = []

    # Manage a get request
    def get(self, request):
        
        ''' Display all the products in our database if no id is passed 
            and if a store ID and search is passed then use those parameters'''
        
        # Get all the parameters sent in the data 
        store_id = request.GET.get('store_id', None)
        search_query = request.GET.get('search')
        category = request.GET.get('category')

        print(store_id, search_query, category)
        queryset = Product.get_all_products()
        
        # Apply filters to the data
        if store_id:
            queryset = queryset.filter(store=store_id)
        
        if category:
            queryset = queryset.filter(category=category)
        
        if search_query: 
            pass 
            names = queryset.filter(name__icontains=search_query)
            descriptions = queryset.filter(description__icontains=search_query)

            # Iterate through the names and get all ids 
            ids = []
            for i in range(len(names)):
                ids.append(names[i].id)
                print(type(names[i].id), print(type(names[i])))
            
            # iterate through descriptions 
            for i in range(len(descriptions)): 
                if descriptions[i].id not in ids:
                    ids.append(descriptions[i].id)
            
            queryset = Product.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
        
        return Response(ProductSerializer(queryset, many = True).data)
```